# Symfony 4 Retreiving the User's Email on Failed Login

Tags: php, symfony

I have created an event listener to increment a failed login count when a user's login attempt fails but am unable to fetch the username associated with the request, which in this case is the user's email.

```
class LoginFailureListener
{
    private $requestStack;
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureEvent $event)
    {   
        $email = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUsername();
        dump($email);
```

The value of $email is an empty string... I have seen other examples where getUsername() seems to return the expected value.

In my User model I have defined the following:

```
/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return (string) $this->email;
}
```

security.yaml:

```
 providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
firewalls:
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                username_parameter: "email"
                password_parameter: "password"
```

Is there another place I need to configure getUsername so that it returns the user's identifier (email)?

The following yielded the required information:

```
$email = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getCredentials()['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no other place where you must configure getUsername(), but in your Entity - and that seems to be Ok.

My suggestion (and $200 bet), is that maybe there is not authenticationToken, because precisely the User failed to enter valid credentials.
However, even anonymous users have a session token, so you could try this:

Inject ContainerInterface $container in your listener's constructor, then try

```
$token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
$user = $token->getUser();
$email = $this->container->get('session')->get('_security.last_username');
dump($token, $user, $email);
```

If there's no email, then it's probably because it was not set in the session right after the login attempt.
Symfony usually does this right after a login, with any class that extends the AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator, in method getCredentials()

```
$request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Hope this helps you mate. Best of luck.

EDIT : your security.yaml seems Ok too, but make sure you have defined your form login below, according to these guidelines:

```
            form_login:
                login_path: login # or whatever your path is
                check_path: login # or whatever your path is
                username_parameter: login[email] # these fields need to be as they appear in the html form
                password_parameter: login[password]
                default_target_path: index # or whatever your path is
            provider: app_user_provider
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I just posted an expanded view of my security.yaml. I am attempting the solution you proposed now

Comment: I suggest you use a browser to Inspect the form's elements (their names), but they're probably valid since otherwise no one would be able to log in. Best of luck.

Comment: It looks like I may have an authToken as when I dump that directly (post updated) I can see the posted email.

Comment: @user1392897 Then you're good to go. Welcome to Symfony bro. Golden rule: you need to dump :-)